# How do I get notified when a program starts running on Linux?

Tags: backup

My computer isn't too fast, and I get daily backups with Timeshift. But it is not clear what time of day this program is running.

While it is working in the background, my computer slows down and I don't understand why. I want to be notified as soon as the Timeshift program is running. How can I do that?

(My distro is Zorin OS 15.0 - 64.bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Timeshift** runs a script every hour to see if it needs to create a new snapshot (based on the snapshot options you selected). If you run this:

```
sudo timeshift --list
```

you will see when each snapshot is created; here's an example from my PC:

```
/dev/sda5 is mounted at: /mnt/timeshift/backup, options: rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/
Device : /dev/sda5
UUID   : 2877dfa4-3adf-446b-8892-3b069e669003
Path   : /mnt/timeshift/backup
Mode   : BTRFS
Device is OK
13 snapshots, 87.5 GB free

Num     Name                 Tags  Description       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    >  2019-11-06_13-07-11  O M   Initial snapshot  
1    >  2019-11-20_14-00-02  W                       
2    >  2019-11-27_14-00-01  W                       
3    >  2019-12-04_14-00-02  W                       
4    >  2019-12-06_14-00-02  M                       
5    >  2019-12-11_14-00-02  W                       
6    >  2019-12-11_17-00-01  D                       
7    >  2019-12-12_17-00-01  D                       
8    >  2019-12-13_17-00-02  D                       
9    >  2019-12-14_17-00-02  D                       
10   >  2019-12-15_17-00-01  D                       
11   >  2019-12-16_17-00-02  D                       
12   >  2019-12-17_17-00-01  D   >>> run @ 5:00PM on 12/17/2019 <<<
```

The main processes that **Timeshift** uses are **rsync** (I'm assuming that you do not have BTRFS partitions, correct?) and **rm** (used for snapshot removal). Open another terminal and run **top** to monitor when these processes are running. If your PC is slow during snapshot creation - using an HDD and/or low RAM, for example - there's not going to be a lot you can do about it while **Timeshift** is running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is enough for me. I'm going to do a review with the Top command.